# OnLongClick with Text View & Edit Text

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener

In Android can the OnLongClickListener be used with EditTexts and TextViews or just Buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OnLongClick handling is inherited from android.view.View. Therefore it should be functional with EditText and TextView too.

Answer (score 1):

It can be used on the base class `View` so also on every derived class. In other words. Yes you can. Reflink to the [OnLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) interface.